# Best way to count results on multiple many to many linked tables

Tags: web, many-to-many, rdbms

Im using php and mysql for an eshop. When in the products section for every category i need a nav with all applicable brands and the number of products. My problem is that the categories and products is a many to many relation as is the products and compatible brands. Therefore when viewing a category the naive approach would be to fetch all products (through a products_categories table), for each fetch all compatible brands(through a products_brands table) and count them. From my research i have also found that joins on multiple tables are expensive in this case 4 joins would be needed. Another idea i had would be to create tables to hold this information, but this would require extra operations when adding/removing categories, products, brands etc and might end in a maintenance nightmare. Is there a better approach?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can escape the joins with given design. You can slightly improve by creating a view between Products_Categories and Products_Brands. This will allow you better optimized way of querying these data from different context (Products, Categories, Brands). And instead of joining the master tables for description, I would separately query those tables and put a caching strategy on it and let client deal with collating ids with descriptions. Hope this makes sense.